# Accessing parent controls from a user control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have a RadTabStrip on my parent.aspx page:

```
<telerik:RadTabStrip ID="rm_comparable" runat="server"
    MultiPageID="Data"
    CausesValidation="False" Enabled="false"
    Height="100%"
    ShowBaseLine="True">
    <Tabs>
        <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Property" Selected="True" >
        </telerik:RadTab>
        <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Sales" >
        </telerik:RadTab>
    </Tabs>
</telerik:RadTabStrip>

<telerik:RadMultiPage ID="Data" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0">

    <telerik:RadPageView ID="mainData" runat="server">
        <uc1:propertyData runat="server" ID="propertyData"/>
    </telerik:RadPageView>

    <telerik:RadPageView ID="salesData" runat="server">
        <uc1:salesRecords ID="salesRecords" runat="server" />
    </telerik:RadPageView>

</telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

and use this code to try to change the control.

```
Private Sub enableTabStrip()
    Dim myTabControl As RadTabStrip = DirectCast(Me.Parent.FindControl("rm_comparable"), RadTabStrip)
    myTabControl.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

When I call the code when the page loads the tab strip is then enabled.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load        
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        enableTabStrip()
    End If
End Sub
```

When I move the code I am calling out of the page load event, my RadTabStrip doesn't become available to the users as it did when I called the event in the page load.

```
Protected Sub btn_addAppraisal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_addAppraisal.Click
    enableTabStrip()
End Sub
```

I am wondering why this functionality will only work in the page load event.

Comment: What do you mean by "available to the users"?  Can you not access its control in the code-behind, or is there an exception being thrown on the page?

Comment: I am unable to access the control in the code behind. There isn't an exception thrown, my radTabStrip just never becomes enabled with the code is not located inside of the page_load event

Comment: In Page_Init the ViewState is not loaded yet and it will likely override your setting. So, where else but on Page_Load would you need that?
Check your references (e.g., is the tabstip object found), make sure if you are using AJAX that it is part of the partial postback.
Also, consider raising events from the user controls that the main page can consume in order to do something. It is much cleaner.